# Howto check if a TreeMap contains a specific object?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, treemap

In an application I have this **TreeMap** object:

```
treePath = new TreeMap<String, DLFolder>();
```

The first String parameter should be the key and the DLFolder is the value.

Ok the **DLFolder** object have this method **dlFolder.getPath()** that return a **String**

So I want to know if the **treePath** object contains a **DLFolder** object having a specific **path** value

Can I do this thing?

Tnx

Comment: Just `treePath.containsKey(folder.getPath())` assuming that's the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (DLFolder dlf : treePath.values()) {
if ("A SPECIFIC PATH".equals(dlf.getPath()) {
// do someting with the dlf
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 this is rather straightforward.

```
treePath.values().anyMatch(dlf -> dlf.getPath().equals(specificValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the values of the `TreeMap`:

```
for (DLFoder folder : treePath.values())
    if (folder.getPath().equals(somePathValue))
        // path found!
```

Answer (score 1):

If the map's key is also the value stored in `dlFolder.getPath()`, then yes, you can just call `treePath.contains("Value");`.

Other options include:

1. Iterating over `treePath`'s values either using an iterator, an enhanced for loop, or the Java 8 streams.
2. Creating another map to map the same `DLFolder` objects, but by path.